# Speech Recognition - An HMM approach

Tags: signals, signal-processing, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

theory really.

I'm going to be developing a speech algorithm and somehow have to build a HMM (Hidden Markov Model) now I get the basic idea of one.. That it is used for probability, and this can be used in Speech recognition. Ok so I found this quote from a website:

"A HMM is constructed for each word in the vocabulary, and then the string of phones is compared against each HMM, to determine which model is the most likely match."

Now I kind of get this, but, what I do not understand is.. For a HMM to be implemented, do I need to take each word in the vocabulary (i.e. in the english dictionary) and it's frequency and then take the frequencies of the Phones? The HMM would find the most accurate word for the Phone?

I hope someone can answer this,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Disregard Daphne Koller's PGM course on coursera, it doens't really address your question.
There is a very good paper that provides a thorough introduction to HMMs and explains how the speech recognition problem is handled. 
The paper is called "[A Tutorial on Hidden Markov Models and Selected Applications in Speech Recognition](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.131.2084)" by Lawrence R. Rabiner.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you check out Dr. Daphne Koller's Probabilistic Graphical Models course on Coursera.org @ https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm

This course covers Hidden Markov Models and machine learning applications.

Comment: The course does take a lot of time however, and does not spend that much time on HMM.